# Creating an animation to run when window loads

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, window, eventtrigger

I have created an animation that takes 400 milliseconds to run, and attached it to an `EventTrigger` for the `Loaded` `RoutedEvent` of my `Window`.

But I think the window doesn't show up right away after it's loaded*, so I can't see the animation at all.

What are some common patterns for running animations when a `Window` loads?

And also, when should I run animations in separate threads?

<sub>* It probably draws the window after it is loaded and it shows the window after it's finished drawing, clarification would be helpful.</sub>

Comment: Do you want it at the begining of the problem or when a specific window opens up in your program? .NET do offer to setup a splash screen. The animation could just be a animated gif.

Comment: It will run both when it loads and when it changes the window (or some content). Just imagine that the animation is similar to how it looks when you start Windows 8, the way all the tiles get animated when you go to Start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the solutions suggested in the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8886941/494094

- `Window.ContentRendered`
- `UIElement.LayoutUpdated`
- `Window.Activated`

So far, `Window.Activated` event seems to suit me best. The only caveat is that none of those events are `RoutedEvent`s, so you need to define the animation in the code behind like the following:

```
this.Activated += (sender, args) => ((Storyboard) FindResource("MyAnimation")).Begin();
```

Answer (score 0):

400 Miliseconds is pretty fast, so a loading window can take longer. I'd suggest keeping it in the same thread, but using a timer event.[Timer Interval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval.aspx) to delay it until the window is fully loaded.

I use the time events for splash screens, etc... and would do the same, I am sure, for a timed animation. It just takes a little practice. My suggestion is to use a long delay on the time to make sure it acts the way you want... then reduce the timer to put it where you want in the load screen.

Comment: Isn't there a better way to tell when the screen is completely drawn and visible on user's screen?

Comment: You can try using the Shown Event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx

Comment: My apologies. I, silly enough, missed that tag. Not as familiar, but you could try an event on load when the IsVisible property is true.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I seem to have found a solution that works for now.

Comment: No problem. Glad you found a solution :)